Unable to get ssh key based authentication working with MobaXTerm
hello I am running MobaXTerm 24.0 and am able to connect to the remote server fine using password authentication but not using ssh keys. I'm also able to ssh directly to the server (I'm using Cygwin's implementation of ssh). In the Configuration settings for SSH agents I've pointed it at the id_rsa.pub file in .ssh but I keep getting "Network error: Connection refused". I tried to add the public key manually but it seems to only accept PuTTY key files, I don't know how to get it to look at the id_rsa.pub as I'd rather not bring Windows ssh impl into the picture as that's likely to screw things up as Windows tends to do. Any idea what's going wrong?

At a minimum we need the following.  Verbose logs from the server as the client attempts to connect.  Verbose logs from the client as it connects.  Your full OpenSSH configuration file for OpenSSH. We also screenshots of the permissions on the private and public key, to verify only the user of the key, has access to the private key.  You should [edit] your question to include this vital information.
